# Open a new tab in firefox and keep ff in the background

Tags: language-agnostic, firefox, command-line, tabs

Is the a way to programmatically open a URL in a new tab in firefox without firefox gaining focus?
What I found out so far:

- `firefox -new-window <URL>` lets ff stay in the background, but opens a new window instead of a tab.

  `firefox -new-tab <URL>` opens <URL> in a new tab but gives focus to ff.

EDIT: What I'm trying to accomplish is making the feed reader plugin in claws mail open stuff in firefox in the background, so that I can go through my feeds and open everything that interests me and actually read all the stuff after that.
Oh and I should probably mention that a linux/gnome-only solution would be fine, too.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? this smells like adware.

Comment: What language are you launching from?

Comment: You could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozmill, and control it through python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground to true in about:config then -new-tab will open tabs in the background and not focus the window.  This does more than you (or I) want but perhaps it is a suitable work-around for you?

Comment: I don't see how this does more than I want. Care to elaborate?

Comment: This actually has a the VERY nice side affect of making my links in gmail popup in tabs and not steal the focus

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can set your firefox to open new tabs in the background. If you programatically open a new tab it might open it in the background. If anything it might be worth trying.

Comment: The only thing I can find would be disabling "when I open a link in a new tab, switch to it immediately" under "tabs" in the ff preferences. I already tried that and it doesn't have any effect on that.

Answer (score -1):

You found the new tab parameter, so you're just missing the focus thing.

That ought to be window manager-dependent I think. Isn't something firefox itself is responsible for. If there's a pointy clicky tool to tune the way metacity does that then I'm unaware of it.