# Open a New Page tab in the background (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tabs

```
<%= link_to StackOverflow, 'https://stackoverflow.com/',  :target => '_blank' %>
```

How do I make a link that opens in a new background tab? The above code opens the link of StackOverflow in a foreground tab.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

I found an answer from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814261/html-how-to-open-a-link-in-the-background?lq=1)

```
$('a[target="_blank"]').removeAttr('target');
```

***How to do it in Ruby/Rails?***

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086988/how-do-i-make-link-to-open-external-urls-in-a-new-window

Comment: It's more similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498530/open-a-new-tab-in-firefox-and-keep-ff-in-the-background?rq=1

How do I do that the Ruby/Rails way?.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to StackOverflow, 'http://stackoverflow.com/',  :target => 'new' %>
```